# regex in .htaccess: force http with optional params, lead the rest to https

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Good day!

**I'm trying to redirect to *http* the following:**
- module/run
- module/run/
- module/run/d{3} (matching natural number with 3 digits)
**The rest should go to *https***
for example module/rundmc

So I'm trying to make things optional but am failing:

**CODE**

```
# ######################################################################
# → Forcing `https://` with exception(s)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/module/run(/d{3})?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

# → Forcing http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /module/run(/d{3})?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

I can't figure it out, as soon as I add the $ sign to it it stops working.

Thank you kind person of the interwebz.

**edit:** 
Maybe I should explain why I'm asking the question:
pages like /module/rundmc are also forced to http but I just need the 3 scenarios listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THE_REQUEST` has much more stuff after REQUEST_URI. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

You can use:

```
# ######################################################################
# → Forcing `https://` with exception(s)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/module/run(/\d{3}|/)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# → Forcing http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/module/run(/\d{3}|/)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: How can I use the $ sign properly in order to determine the end of the regex? thx

Comment: You don't need to use `$` sign because URI has either `?` at start of query string or `\sHTTP`. So we just match `[\s?]`

Comment: It works for module/run and module/run/ but not for module/run/123. I just don't get it.

Comment: ah you had `d{3}` instead of `\d{3}`, try updated answer now,